# I need to create a list only with the repeated items from another list

Tags: python, string, list, nltk, operation

I have a list with repeated items like:

```
    Movies = ['Batman Return', 'Minions', 'Slow Burn', 
'Defensor', 'Minions', 'Batman Return', 
'All is lost', 'Minions']
```

You can see that there are two repeated items, and I need created a list with only this elements like that:

```
Top_Movies = ['Batman Return', 'Minions']
```

Order is important.

I know how delete repeated items but I don't know how to do the opposite.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what is your python version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter


Movies = ['Batman Return', 'Minions', 'Slow Burn', 
'Defensor', 'Minions', 'Batman Return', 
'All is lost', 'Minions']

Top_Movies = [k for k, v in Counter(Movies).items() if v > 1]
Top_Movies
```

output:

```
['Batman Return', 'Minions']
```

the order is guaranteed if you use a python version >= 3.6